# Does JavaScript Date object recognises the input datestring as UTC time or local time?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

There are already quite a number of questions regarding time, but I still couldn't find one that can answer my question. So, I have to apologise if this is a repeat. My question is this:

I have a MySQL table column named `postDate` in `datetime` format. My server is on system time (UTC). I have the following php script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var expiry = new Date('$postDate');
 alert(expiry);
</script>

$postDate = date("r", strtotime($postDate)); // sorry forgot to add this line
```

I just want to know, assuming `$postDate` is `2012-03-30 01:00:00`, and the client is on a +8hr time zone, what will he see on the alert? I.e. does JavaScript `Date` object recognises the `datestring` as UTC time or local time?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Change your computers clock setting and run the script. Or try to run it with the hard-coded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the user's locale, that will fail with the result "Invalid Date".

Instead, you should pass a timestamp. Timestamps are ALWAYS in UTC. To get a timestamp from your `datetime` format, run it through [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime). But bear in mind that JS does timestamps in milliseconds, not seconds, so you have to add an extra `000` to the end.

So basically:

```
$postDate = strtotime($postDate)."000";
```

The result of the alert will still depend on the user's timezone, but it will be correctly offset from the UTC timestamp you gave. For example, if the timestamp is 1AM UTC, but the user is in UTC+8, they will see 9AM.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know that the `datestring` must be a timestamp.

Comment: It doesn't "have" to be, but it makes it easier because it doesn't depend on locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

[image]and yes, [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/t4p3M/), amazing. just 2 lines of code in a fiddle.

Comment: @Kolink it alerts fine on my browser, see image in updated answer

Comment: I addressed the issue of formats in my answer - just because it works for one person in one locale doesn't mean it'll work for all.